# PIMCore Call to a member function supportsInheritance() on null

Tags: pimcore

Whenever I click on search button to select object from list as shown in image below.

[image]

I get the error Call to a member function supportsInheritance() on null. It was working  but today its started showing this error. Image showing error is below

[image]

I already have lists to select by searching and it was working today.
I have created fields inside bricks and using bricks inside classes.

Below is the full details of Error.

[image]

Any solution will be appreciated. My pimcore version is 6.6.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you click on "Details" and add the full exception to the question please?

Comment: @Blackbam I have included exception Details. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Either you have changed your class definitions recently or you have added/imported Objects with empty localized fields. Populate the localized fields in your object and find the problematic field, then the Exception will be gone.

Read more:

https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/2809

https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/2810

https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/6658

If you think you found a bug within the Pimcore system itself create a new bug report which is as specific as possible in https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/.

Comment: I had this issue after adding inheritance to an existing class definition which contained localized fields. Re-saving the data object in the admin UI fixed it for me.